# Hive - Create Table statement with 'select query' and 'fields terminated by' commands

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to create a table in Hive using a select statement which takes a subset of a data from another table. I used the following query to do so :

```
create table sample_db.out_table as 
select * from sample_db.in_table where country = 'Canada';
```

When I looked into the HDFS location of this table, there are no field separators.

But I need to create a table with filtered data from another table along with a field separator. For example I am trying to do something like :

```
create table sample_db.out_table as 
select * from sample_db.in_table where country = 'Canada'
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

This is not working though. I know the alternate way is to create a table structure with field names and the "FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'" command and then load the data.

**But is there any other way to combine the two into a single query that enables me to create a table with filtered data from another table and also with a field separator ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `row format delimited ..` in front of  `AS select`

do  it  like this 
   Change the  query  to yours

```
hive> CREATE TABLE ttt  row format delimited fields terminated by '|' AS select *,count(1) from t1 group by id ,name  ;
Query ID = root_20180702153737_37802c0e-525a-4b00-b8ec-9fac4a6d895b
```

here is the result

```
[root@hadoop1 ~]# hadoop fs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/ttt/**
2|\N|1
3|\N|1
4|\N|1
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [the documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)), when using the CTAS (*Create Table As Select*) statement, the `ROW FORMAT` statement (in fact, all the settings related to the new table) goes **before** the `SELECT` statement.